# How to check which version of Xamarin was used to create the project

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, xamarin-studio

I keep getting `Could not find type 'System.Globalization.SortVersion'` exception.
This seems to be a bug in Xamarin.The workaround is to disable msbuild -- > which produces a theming error (OR) to use the same version of xamarin studio.
So how can i check which version of Xamarin Studio was used to create the project?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i do when i want to check the version of xamarin used and/or Visual studio used during the course of the project development.

- Open the **sample.sln** residing in project folder using any text
  editor(Like Notepad++). Below is the screen shot that shows VS
  version if it was created using Visual studio

[image]

- Navigate to **sample.droid** folder (Your Android project). open the
  **packages.config** using any text editor(Like Notepad++). Below is the
  screeshot that shows the xamarin forms version(in my case) used and android
  runtime used to create the project.

[image]

Based on this info you can checkout the release logs available on [xamarin](http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/) portal and downgrade your studio accordingly.

Comment: Thanks,but im not developing an Android project.its a desktop application with GTK GUI.I tried opening the main .sln file.it says VS 11 but i have created it using Xamarin Studio.There is no *.config files in the dir.